# replace with auto-generated random number

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am trying to append a list of strings with a random number 2-3 digit in sublime text, so what I did is to do find and replace:

```
\n
```

with

```
[0-9]*\n
```

however this automatically translate as is, how can I replace with an autogenerated number in sublime ? is it even possible?

Comment: There's this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Random%20Everything, but I don't think it's possible with search and replace in sublime, It is very simple with any programming language and in case this is a one-off thing you can even copy-paste to excel

Answer (score -1):

this is the php code to generate random 3 digit number which you can use to replace

```
 $characters = '0123456789';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];

}
```

Comment: It's likely that the OP wants it to be done in sublime text.

Comment: I can do it in php, but I don't want to.. I want it in sublime